# How do I change all the Silverlight Telerik RadButton colors at run time?

Tags: silverlight, telerik

This question is in regard to the Telerik RadButtons for Silverlight. I have themes per customer on the site where Silverlight is used.  I am able to change the background and foreground colors by setting the Background and Foreground brush properties.  However, the styles revert to the standard colors while hovering over the button.  How do I change the colors for all button states?

I attempted to set the Resources dictionary as shown on [Telerik Styles](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radbuttons-styles-and-templates-styling-the-radbutton.html), but it appears to be read-only.

Answer (score 0):

More information on how to style a RadButton you can find here: http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radbuttons-styles-and-templates-overview.html

Comment: I don't see new information on that page and the RadButton link points to the URL I showed in my question.  What am I missing?